# Windows 2003 - DFS not replicating all the files?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dfs

Is there a way to force DFS replication to happen? I've added another share to an existing DFS link, and it's 24 hours later, and the 2 folders are not in sync! The newly added share has only about 30% of the files there.

I could have manually copied the data to the two servers shares in 10 minutes, but i didn't want to risk messing up anyones permissions.

This is a touch worrying for me here, as the backups will be incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the event log to ensure that DFS isn't complaining about anything. The most common one is that it encountered a file larger than its staging space, and stopped replication.

If this is the case you'll need to [increase the staging space](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264822), or snipe the file out of the share to things can continue.

Just a word of caution - Don't manually copy files from one folder to another if they're both supposed to be replicating with DFS. It'll get in a big tizzy if you try and manually override it.

Comment: Thanks for this! I can't believe I've left this question open for so long! IIRC, DFS was spewing all kinds of madness into the logs - It was easier to rip it out and start again. Worked like a charm tho'

Answer (score 0):

Try advertising the replication group to the domain. It's done under DFS management, and it is  under Replications groups.